# Strange angular js error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am facing a strange angular js error. I am building an angular app. I am not very much proficient in angular. However I have successfully created some complex app. Now I am having a error in the browser console.

I can't understand the error a bit. The error shows stackFrame.js. But in my project there is no such js and I have searched web about it and I could not find any thing and the error is very fragile also. Once the error appears all angular activities are not working any more.

I can only attach the screen shot and the `'question_set.js (line 249)'` is my code and on that line I have used `$scope.$apply()`.

One more thing I would like to say that I used jquery ajax instead of angular http service. Because In `yii2` the angular http does not populate the post data properly. I only can provide the screen shot.

[image: The error which I get in my browser console. And I don't know what is the error about href is null]

Thanks in advance. If anyone and kindly give any clue. Specially the angular masters.

Comment: Can you add some code?

Comment: I think href is null

Comment: @AbhisekMalakar how we suggest any answer to your question if we don't have any code to see. There could be some minor problem you can post the code and then people in here could help you better.

Comment: @Jai  Yes, Actually the code is huge. And I think what to post. Can I post my complete js file?

Comment: use e.g. jsfiddle to create an example which represents your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error "href is null" seems to be a bug in Firebug according to this SO-post: [AngularJS doesn't show specific errors in the Firebug console anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32836064/angularjs-doesnt-show-specific-errors-in-the-firebug-console-anymore) .
The error is hiding an actual error in your code, but you can't see it because of the bug in Firebug. Try the default developer tools in Firefox or try another browser to find out what your actual error is.

Comment: Thanks. I will try and let you know. And if it works , it will be  a great help