# AngularJS doesn't show specific errors in the Firebug console anymore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebug, angular-material

I am using AngularJS along with the angular-material library in my application. 
The problem is, whenever any error occurs in any function of the controller, it doesn't show the specific error but instead shows the same generic error everytime, by looking at which you cannot determine what went wrong.

Here is the error shown in my console.

```
TypeError: href is null   stackFrame.js (line 357)
consoleLog/<()   angular.js (line 12416)
$ExceptionHandlerProvider/this.$get</<()   angular.js (line 9203)
processQueue()   angular.js (line 14642)
scheduleProcessQueue/<()   angular.js (line 14650)
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$eval()   angular.js (line 15878)
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$digest()   angular.js (line 15689)
$RootScopeProvider/this.$get</Scope.prototype.$apply()   angular.js (line 15986)
done()   angular.js (line 10511)
completeRequest()   angular.js (line 10683)
requestLoaded()   angular.js (line 10624)
```

Here is the screenshot of that error.
[image: Error as shown in Firebug]

PS: I am using the RequireJS JavaScript library to lazy-load my application. I am also using ui.router in my application.

**Update 1:**
stackFrame.js is not a JavaScript file of my application. The location of stackFrame.js is:

```
chrome://firebug/content/debugger/stack/stackFrame.js
```

And it always shows the same error on the same line throughout my application in any controller, even if I face different errors in the application.

**Update 2:**

Disabling Firebug works. It shows the specific error in Firefox´ and Chrome´s console.
I would like to add, that this type of error is shown in Firebug when there is an error inside the response function of `$http.post()`. Testing further cases.

**Update 3:**

With reference to https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7948, this issue has been solved in firebug 2.0.13.

Comment: Error shows what went wrong: stackFrame.js, line 357, href is null, Type error. It doesn't help you?

Comment: stackFrame.js isn't a js file of my application. Please see the update.

Comment: @MohitAdwani: did you try disabling firebug?

Comment: Oh, sure. Just get rid of Firebug, use built-in dev tools.

Comment: @Shivi Disabling firebug works. The normal console of firefox shows the specific error. But i need firebug for development purposes.

Comment: @MohitAdwani: U can try running the same project in Chrome too. It has a better Dev tools console than firefox. Or Firefox is a necessity..??

Comment: @Shivi Honestly I am used to firebug now. And it is necessary at somepoint for me to test it first on firefox. I never test things in chrome because if it works on firefox properly, it should work on chrome as well, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Ya, but then the vice-versa is also true. :P ... Anyways, atleast for figuring out bugs, u may use chrome, because firebug does act faulty sometimes...

Comment: Will do. I can anyways fireup the native console to check the exact error. Thank you @Shivi.

Comment: Just want to add that this also just started happening for me (FF 41.0, FB 2.0.12, OSX). Like the OP, I like Firebug and I prefer FF over Chrome since mostly what works on FF works on Chrome. However, I find that whatever works on Chrome doesn't always work on FF since it's sometimes behind on the newest W3C features

Comment: @user193130 I agree. I am on FF 41.0 and FB 2.0.12 as well.

Comment: [Linked issue from Github](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/7948) in case others want to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is obviously a bug in Firebug. The related line within its code is this one:

https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/a389cf78b310aedf33531520cc11f1e05051ecc3/extension/content/firebug/debugger/stack/stackFrame.js#L357

If you want this to get fixed, you should [file a bug report for Firebug](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues/new).

Comment: I have already filed an issue on their github repo. Lets see what is their reply.

Comment: You [filed it](https://github.com/firebug/firebug.next/issues/413) in the Firebug.next repository, which is wrong. (That is for future major versions of Firebug.) You need to file it in the [Firebug repository](https://github.com/firebug/firebug/issues). Also, in the issue you should refer back to this SO question and try to break your issue down to a simple test case, so the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: Sorry. I did not know that. Let me change that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom exception handling in AngularJs.

```
app.config(function($provide){

    $provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", function($delegate, $injector){
        return function(exception, cause){
            var $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
            $rootScope.addError({message:"Exception", reason:exception});
            $delegate(exception, cause);
        };
    });

});
```

It will send all errors to $rootScope for data binding before allowing the call to fall through to the default implementation (addError is a custom method on $rootScope, while $delegate represents the service being decorated).

errors service to encapsulate some of the common logic.

```
app.factory("errors", function($rootScope){
    return {
        catch: function(message){
            return function(reason){
                $rootScope.addError({message: message, reason: reason})
            };
        }
    };
});
```

Handling Error:

```
 TestService.doWork().then()               
        .catch(errors.catch("Could not complete work!"));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I need to know why this is happening in firebug. I have not implemented what you have suggested and i might implement that. But thats not the answer i am looking for. Sorry

Comment: href is null means some service is not getting proper response or may be if you are using ng-repeat your json structure not appropriate.You can implement it and then you will know exact error.
This will save your time of debugging.

Comment: Yes. I am getting this error inside response function of $http.post. This error is shown vaguely in firebug but in default console of browsers its showing exactly what is wrong.  Is this some kind of bug in firebug or something else entirely ?

Comment: that's good you found cause ..yeah,might be a issue of firebug, anyway you are using firebug in chrome or Mozilla ?

Comment: Mozilla. Cannot use firebug of chrome as it doesn't support localhost as far as i know.

Comment: i believe it'll support . may be some configuration changes require. Anyways if my answer help you in any way then you can  raise flag.
Happy Coding !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90857/discussion-between-mohit-adwani-and-shrinath).